# tensorflow, InvalidArgumentError: image_size must contain 3 elements[4]

Tags: tensorflow, element, image-size, invalid-argument

Error:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError'>, image_size must contain 3 elements[4]
[[Node: distort_image/distorted_bounding_box_crop/sample_distorted_bounding_box/SampleDistortedBoundingBoxV2 = SampleDistortedBoundingBoxV2[T=DT_INT32, area_range=[0.05, 1], aspect_ratio_range=[0.75, 1.33], max_attempts=100, seed=0, seed2=0, use_image_if_no_bounding_boxes=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](distort_image/distorted_bounding_box_crop/Shape, distort_image/Const, distort_image/distorted_bounding_box_crop/sample_distorted_bounding_box/SampleDistortedBoundingBoxV2/min_object_covered)]]
INFO:tensorflow:Finished training! Saving model to disk.
INFO:tensorflow:Recording summary at step 1300607.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "train_image_classifier.py", line 615, in 
tf.app.run()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
_sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
File "train_image_classifier.py", line 611, in main
session_config=sess_config)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/learning.py", line 775, in train
sv.stop(threads, close_summary_writer=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 792, in stop
stop_grace_period_secs=self._stop_grace_secs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/coordinator.py", line 389, in join
six.reraise(*self._exc_info_to_raise)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/queue_runner_impl.py", line 238, in _run
enqueue_callable()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1231, in _single_operation_run
target_list_as_strings, status, None)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 473, in exit
c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: image_size must contain 3 elements[4]
[[Node: distort_image/distorted_bounding_box_crop/sample_distorted_bounding_box/SampleDistortedBoundingBoxV2 = SampleDistortedBoundingBoxV2[T=DT_INT32, area_range=[0.05, 1], aspect_ratio_range=[0.75, 1.33], max_attempts=100, seed=0, seed2=0, use_image_if_no_bounding_boxes=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](distort_image/distorted_bounding_box_crop/Shape, distort_image/Const, distort_image/distorted_bounding_box_crop/sample_distorted_bounding_box/SampleDistortedBoundingBoxV2/min_object_covered)]]
```

A very curious problem, when the model is trained, caused by the function `tf.image.sample_distorted_bounding_box()`

> InvalidArgumentError: image_size must contain 3 elements[4]
>   Sometimes it's okay to restart training, but sometimes it's always wrong.

I do not know how to solve it.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Please post your code.  Also, are you actually getting the message "Sometimes it's okay to restart training, but sometimes it's always wrong."?  I don't see it in your traceback and I don't know where it could possibly come from.

Comment: sorry, my expression bad. code is `slim` project in tensorflow models, run `train_image_classifier.py`,  now, it`s always raise: "InvalidArgumentError: image_size must contain 3 elements[4]" in training.
error info like:
INFO:tensorflow:global step 1322330: loss = 4.8617 (0.637 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 1322340: loss = 4.4511 (0.636 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 1322350: loss = 4.7013 (0.636 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError'>, image_size must contain 3 elements[4]....

Comment: According to "[[Node: distort_image / distorted_bounding_box_crop / sample_distorted_bounding_box / SampleDistortedBoundingBoxV2]]",  I found error from `preprocessing/inception_preprocessing.py`, function: `distorted_bounding_box_crop()`->`sample_distorted_bounding_box = tf.image.sample_distorted_bounding_box(...)`

Comment: solved the problem!  click here: [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/3349)

Comment: Hi sir! Did you find what was the reason for this error? I also have the same error. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the party, Got the same error & there was a warning before this that exactly tells that there are 4 dimensions to the tensor instead of 3. Figured the issue is you have to converted from SRGB to JPG and remove the BG.

Heres a script to do that. Courtesy of the tensorflow [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/3349)

```
from PIL import Image     
import os       
path = 'SET YOUR PATH' # Source Folder 
for file in os.listdir(path):      
        extension = file.split('.')[-1]
        if extension == 'jpg':
            fileLoc = path+file
            img = Image.open(fileLoc)
            if img.mode != 'RGB':
                print(file+', '+img.mode)
                new = Image.new("RGB", img.size, (255, 255, 255))
                new.paste(img,None)
                new.save(file, 'JPEG', quality=100)
```